# tensorflow installation error in rasa_core package

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, rasa-core

Tried a lot of things to rectify the problem but nothing helped. tried downloading tensorflow separately but while installing `rasa_core` again the same problem is coming. I have a `32 bit` machine with `python 3.6.5` installed and with the latest version of pip.

[image]

I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow causes a lot of problem when installing.

Would be good if you could specify if you are installing the cpu or the gpu version.

Firstly, update your version of pip and try again.

If you are installing the gpu version, then you need to find all the compatible gpus(not all work with tensorflow). You need the exact right version of CUDA(even more recent versions will not work) and there are plenty of other errors that can come up.

I have little experience with the cpu version, I would not recommend using tensorflow on cpu since processing time gets really high even for some basic machine learning. You can get a GT740 for under $90

I would recommend finding a tensorflow tutorial that shows exactly how to install it, get one as recent as possible.

Personally it took me a lot of trial and error getting tensorflow to work so its not uncommon.